# Comparing two uploaded json files

Tags: javascript, json, object-comparison

I'm a beginner at coding and I'm trying to make a code to compare two uploaded .JSON files but I'm stuck as to how to get the value of the .JSON file.

If i use file1.value => its just showing the path of the file like C://fakepath//

I want to get the content of the files

Here is my code at the moment

```
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1">
      <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2">
      <button class="check">check</button>

      <div class="output-container">
        <pre id="output1"></pre>
        <pre id="output2"></pre>
      </div>
```

```
   
const file1 = document.querySelector("#file1");
const file2 = document.querySelector("#file2");
const check = document.querySelector('.check');

check.addEventListener('click', compare);

// let json1, json2 = false;

file1.addEventListener("change", function () {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  const output1 = document.getElementById("output1");

  fr.onload = function () {
    output1.textContent = fr.result;
  };

  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});

file2.addEventListener("change", function () {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  const output2 = document.getElementById("output2");

  fr.onload = function () {
    output2.textContent = fr.result;
  };

  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});


function getDifference(o1, o2) {
  var diff = {};
  var tmp = null;
  if (JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2)) return true;

  for (var k in o1) {
    if (Array.isArray(o1[k]) && Array.isArray(o2[k])) {
      tmp = o1[k].reduce(function(p, c, i) {
        var _t = getDifference(c, o2[k][i]);
        if (_t)
          p.push(_t);
        return p;
      }, []);
      if (Object.keys(tmp).length > 0)
        diff[k] = tmp;
    } else if (typeof(o1[k]) === "object" && typeof(o2[k]) === "object") {
      tmp = getDifference(o1[k], o2[k]);
      if (tmp && Object.keys(tmp) > 0)
        diff[k] = tmp;
    } else if (o1[k] !== o2[k]) {
      diff[k] = o2[k]
    }
  }
  return diff;
}

// var d = getDifference(output1.textContent, output2.textContent);
// console.log(d);

// console.log(output1);
// console.log(output2.textContent);
```

Comment: Where did you get `o1` and `o2` from?

Comment: at the bottom i called the function
`// var d = getDifference(output1.textContent, output2.textContent); // console.log(d);`
but the `ouput1.textContent` is showing as empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the user has set the input, you can dig into the file input to get the file contents like this:

```
const f = document.querySelector("#file1")

f.files[0].text().then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

`f.files` might contain more than 1 item if you set the `multiple` attribute on the input. In your case, you just want the first item.

You might also like to look into the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

---

**Edit**

Wrap your click handler into an async function:

```
// Assign compare function to event listener
const check = document.querySelector(".check");
check.addEventListener('click', compare);

const compare = async () => {

    // Get file inputs
    const file1 = document.querySelector("#file1");
    const file2 = document.querySelector("#file2");

    // Get the file contents by awaiting the promise to resolve
    const contents1 = await file1.files[0].text()
    const contents2 = await file2.files[0].text()

    const difference = getDifference(o1, o2)

}
```

Here is a codesandbox of what it should look like in the end.
https://codesandbox.io/s/comparing-two-uploaded-json-files-39xmp

Comment: oh this is one step closer, 

`file1.files[0].text().then((data) => {
  output1.textContent = data;
});`

now how do i get the data to my getDifference function?
because when i console.log(output.textContent) => it says empty string, because the data is inside that anonymous function

Comment: @Bernard, check my update.

Comment: now i'm more confused hahaha..

i've edited the code above... when i run this, i got this error inside the console.log

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'compare' before initialization
```

Comment: @Bernard Added a code sandbox sample. Possibly a good idea to leave the original question as it was so the context of the answers doesn't get lost for other readers. Just put in an edit with question clarification when needed.

Comment: thank you! another question is .. for the data is it in JSON? or String?

Comment: @Bernard The `.text()` method will return plain text, so you will need to run it through `JSON.parse(contents)`. I've updated the sandbox to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've two JSON data files and both contain the same following values.

FirstFile.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Raju Ahmed",
    "age": 32,
    "country": "Bangladesh"
  }
]
```

SecondFile.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Raju Ahmed 2",
    "age": 32,
    "country": "Bangladesh"
  },
  {
    "name": "Raju Ahmed 2",
    "age": 32,
    "country2": "Bangladesh"
  }
]
```

First I loaded two files. Then read the data in a different textarea (read-only mode). Then compare if both files are matched or not. You can also check it [***LIVE***](https://jsfiddle.net/rajuahmed/82kfxc5z/3/) from here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     table, td, th {
     border: 1px solid black;
     }
     table {
     width: 100%;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="jsonFile" name="jsonFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <fieldset>
    <h2>Json File</h2>
    <table >
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Select First File</th>
             <th>First File Value</th>
             <th>Select Second File</th>
             <th>Second File Value</th>
             <th>Load File</th>
             <th>Compare</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tr>
          <td><input type='file' id='fileinput'></td>
          <td><textarea readonly disabled id="fileOneData" name="fileOneData" placeholder="First File Data"></textarea></td>
          <td><input type='file' id='fileinput2'>    </td>
          <td><textarea readonly disabled id="fileTwoData" name="fileTwoData" placeholder="Second File Data"></textarea></td>
          <td><input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='loadFile()'></td>
          <td><input type='button' id='btnCompare' value='Compare' onclick='Compare()'></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Compare(){
  var fileOneData = document.getElementById("fileOneData").value;
  var fileTwoData = document.getElementById("fileTwoData").value;
  
  var compareResult= JSON.stringify(fileOneData)===JSON.stringify(fileTwoData);
  if(compareResult){
    alert("Both file matched");
  }
  else{
    alert("Both file not matched");
  }
 }
 
  function loadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;
    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
      alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
      return;
    }
 
    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    input2 = document.getElementById('fileinput2');
    if (!input) {
      alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
 else if(!input2){
    alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput 2 element.");
 }
    else if (!input.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
 else if (!input2.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs 2.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
 else if (!input2.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file 2 before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);
   
   file2 = input2.files[0];
      fr2 = new FileReader();
      fr2.onload = receivedText2;
      fr2.readAsText(file2);
    }
 
    function receivedText(e) {
      let lines = e.target.result;
      var newArrOne = JSON.parse(lines);
      document.getElementById('fileOneData').value=lines;     
   
    }
 
  function receivedText2(e) {
      let lines = e.target.result;    
      var newArrTwo = JSON.parse(lines); 
   document.getElementById('fileTwoData').value=lines
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Note:*** If also need to compare data also let me know.

Comment: having the compare data would be great! but i also want to learn not just get the answer, if you know what i mean :)

Comment: @Bernard, you should mention in your question, that you are not expecting only the answer but also a tutorial/explanation. We're here, to help the community but not as paid employees. We feel happy if we make someone happy by investing our valuable time.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm pretty new here.. Thank you for the help.. is it still okay if i see the compare data code?